# Hibernate - synchronize two properties mapping the same column

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Is it possible to keep sync two properties on the same entity mapped to the same column (with basic JPA, or with hibernate)?

I have two properties:

```
@JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, name = "parent", updatable = false)
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Person parent;
@Column(name = "parent")
private Integer parentId;
```

Basically, I would like the following:

```
System.out.println(element.getParentId());
System.out.println(element.getParent().getId());
element.setParentId(2);
System.out.println(element.getParentId());
System.out.println(element.getParent().getId());
```

This to print "3,3,2,2" instead of "3,3,2,3".

Is it possible (without writing a custom lazy-loading on the getParent() getter?)

Thx in advance

Comment: When I use this mapping configuration, Hibernate always gets an error of "Repeated column in mapping for entity", however I'm using the updatable/insertable as you did. Shouldn't that be enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIRC, Hibernate will not do that for you. You're the one responsible if you have something like that (I remembered doing something similiar).

The first solution will be to save the entity first, then refresh using the entity manager.

```
element.setParentId(2);
entityManager.merge(element);
entityManager.refresh(element);
```

Refresh will make it fetch the object from the database again, and it will have the correct value.

The second option which I did, was to change the setter of the entity to maintain the state. Something like:

```
public void setParent(Parent parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
    parentId = parent.id;
}
```

Comment: Thx for the answer. Too bad there isn't any 'automatic' solution for this...
Well, maybe Hibernate's scope is not the in-memory-entity management

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
@JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, name = "parent")
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Person parent;


@Column(name = "parent")
private Integer parentId;
```

If that don't work:

Try this if parentId is the primary key of the Parent entity:

```
@JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, name = "parent")
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Person parent;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerateType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "parent")
private Integer parentId;
```

Try this:

```
@JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "id", name = "parent")
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Person parent;


@Column(name = "parent")
private Integer parentId;
```

If that don't work:

Try this:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "parent")
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Person parent;


@Column(name = "parent")
private Integer parentId;
```

Comment: If I leave out the "updateable" part (as far as I can see, the first solution's change is that) - Hibernate fails, bc it can't handle 2 updateable properties on the same column. The same applies for the other ones - without the "insertable" or the "updateable" attribute parameters, Hibernate can't initialize itself

Answer (score 1):

You can have two properties for the same column like this :

```
@JoinColumn(name = "CGRADO_CODIGO", referencedColumnName = "CGRADO_CODIGO")
    @ManyToOne
    @NotFound(action=NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    private SipreGrado                  sipreGrado;

    @Column(name = "CGRADO_CODIGO",insertable=false,updatable=false)
    private String                      sipreGradoCodigo;
```

Your output in the inspect code will be like this :

```
sipreGradoCodigo   "001"
sipreGrado         null
```

or

```
sipreGradoCodigo   "001"
sipreGrado         Entity SipreGrado ["001","other property","etc"]
```

Remember if you have sometimes the entity NULL you can skip it with that annotation

```
@NotFound(action=NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
```

Also,Remember to set

```
insertable=false,updatable=false
```

for the one that you dont want to include in the insert/update queries.